# TS2305: Module './@angular/material/material' has no exported member 'MaterialModule'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I believe this error has aroused due to an update of the material module from version 10 to 12, but I have found no solution to this issue.
current material module version:

```
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12"
```

in package-lock.json:

```
"@angular/material": {
  "version": "2.0.0-beta.12",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/material/-/material-2.0.0-beta.12.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-cbbQt7AhiR5dDjaIwdS9eMdFf1g=",
  "requires": {
    "tslib": "1.8.0"
  }
},
```

Comment: post your app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

`MaterialModule` has been removed with angular material version `2.0.0-beta.11` for performance reasons (see their [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)). From beta 11 you'll have to import each material module you need separately. Of course you can also create a dedicated module where you'd put all your material modules in and import the module into your root module (or whatever module you will be using it).

For more details you might want to refer to their [roadmap](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#materialmodule) as well, quote:

> We've found that, with the current state of tree-shaking in the world, that using an aggregate `NgModule` like `MaterialModule` leads to tools not being able to eliminate code for components that aren't used.
>
> In order to ensure that users end up with the smallest code size possible, we're deprecating `MaterialModule`, to be removed in the a subsequent release.
>
> To replace `MaterialModule`, users can create their own "Material" module within their application (e.g., `GmailMaterialModule`) that imports only the set of components actually used in the application.