# Error about Angular material module

Tags: angular

I have installed `@angular/material`. It's version `@6.2.1`.

When importing this module in `app.module.ts` its giving error

> Module "c:/Users/Rachana/Angular1/demo1/node_modules/@angular/material/material" has no exported member 'MaterialModule'. Did you mean 'MatRippleModule'?

What could be the reason?

Comment: No problem while adding the flex-layout module but only problem with material module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import Angular Material in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166844/how-to-import-angular-material-in-project)

Comment: If you google the issue, it will point you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948325/ts2305-module-angular-material-material-has-no-exported-member-materialmo

Answer (score 0):

Make sure :

1. what you import is available inside node modules folder eg:node_modules/@angular/material/material, you can see an error if you are using visual studio while importing the module in app.module.ts if file is not available.
2. Module is available inside **import:[yourModule]** array  (in app.module.ts)
3. Module available inside **exports:[yourModule]** array (in app.module.ts)

Comment: node modules/@angular/material.. after this path i can't see the material folder. I can see material.d and material.metadata.json